# Why background-color overlap the box-shadow?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I have a table with cells that have a `background-color`. I'm trying to set the `box-shadow` for the `thead`, but the background of a cells in first column overlaps a shadow. I tried to set a different `z-index` values and `position: relative`, but to no avail.

```css
.results-table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.results-table th,
.results-table td {
    padding: 1em;
    width: 96px;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);
}

.results-table thead {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
  position: relative;
}

.results-table thead th {
    background: #E0E0E0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);
}

.results-table tr:first-child td,
.results-table tr:first-child th {
    border-top: none;
}

.results-table tr th:first-child,
.results-table tr td:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

.item-cell.item-cell {
    width: 128px;
}

td.item-cell.item-cell {
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<table class="results-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="item-cell">
        Item
      </th>
      <th>
        Package
      </th>
      <th>
        Price
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="item-cell">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      </td>
      <td>Package 1</td>
      <td>Price 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="item-cell">
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      </td>
      <td>Package 2</td>
      <td>Price 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="item-cell">
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </td>
      <td>Package 3</td>
      <td>Price 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

By the way, a shadow works in Firefox, but does not work in other browsers.

[Firefox [image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiEs0.png)

[Chrome, Opera, Edge, IE11 [image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wJqj.png)

So how to implement a shadow for the thead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add `z-index` `negative` on `td`

```
.results-table td{
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change this :

```
box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
```

to this :

```
box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
```

Answer (score 0):

thumbs up for Answer # 2. But there is new solution for this old problem i.e [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

```css
body {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}
.container {
  width: 500px;
}

.item {
  background: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px #000;
/*  Solution # 1 Starts */
/*   z-index: -1;
  position:relative */
/*  Solution # 1 Ends */
/*  Solution # 2 Starts */
  clip-path: inset(0 1px 1px);
/*  Solution # 2 End */
}

.cell {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #000;
/*   box-shadow: 0 1px #000; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="item">ITEM 1</div>
    <div class="item">ITEM 2</div>
    <div class="item">ITEM 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```